# checking possible exit code of background process

Tags: bash

Consider the following piece of code:

```
myprocess | while read line; do logger -t mytag -p user.err $line; done &

if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]; then
   logger -t ${tag} -p user.error "CANNOT START (exit code: ${PIPESTATUS[0])"
fi
```

If myprocess does not fail, then the PIPESTATUS[0] is what, undefined?
How can I check if myprocess started or died on startup (missing library symbols etc.), while still capturing its output?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` applies to the most recent *foreground* pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
{ myprocess 2>&1 || echo "CANNOT START (exit code: $?)" ; } \
| while read line; do logger -t mytag -p user.err $line; done
```

The `2>&1` will let you trap and log error output as well as standard output.

Comment: This does not seem to work if I add an & after the done. The script needs to continue, leaving this in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If `myprocess` did not fail, `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` would be `0`.

Alternatively, `set -o pipefail`. Then the exit status of the full command (`$?`) would be non-zero if `myprocess` failed and you wouldn't need to check `PIPESTATUS`.

Answer (score 0):

This can get tricky. You need to return ${PIPESTATUS[n]} ***from*** the backgrounded job. I do something very similar by creating a function and passing in the command to run as an argument then send the whole thing to the background. NOTE the return statement in the pipe_command() function. This returns the status of $cmd as opposed to your while read line loop. You can background multiple things in a for loop using this technique as well. Hope this helps.

Example:

```
#! /bin/bash

main()
{
    pids=""
    myprocess="ssh user@node /bin/bash /etc/init.d/process start"
    pipe_command "$myprocess" &
    pids+="$! "
    watch_pids "$pids"
}

pipe_command()
{
    cmd="$1"
    $cmd 2>&1 | \
    while read line; do
        logger -t mytag -p user.err $line
    done
    return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
}

watch_pids()
{
    pids="$1"
    for pid in $pids; do
        wait $pid
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            logger -t ${tag} -p user.error "CANNOT START (exit code: $?)"
            return 2
        fi
    done
}
main $@
```

Or perhaps more simply put to your example:

```
myprocess | while read line; do logger -t mytag -p user.err $line; done ; return ${PIPESTATUS[0]} &

wait
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
   logger -t ${tag} -p user.error "CANNOT START (exit code: $status)"
fi
```